# Is there a way to set the name of tmux pane? And then refer to that pane in a script by name?

Tags: session, scripting, tmux

I'd like to name a tmux pane so that later in a script I could refer to that pane specifically.  I'm fairly new to tmux.  I have a .tmux configuration and have written a script or two that sets up a window with some panes, but I'm sure I don't really know exactly how it all works together.

Mostly my scripts do something like this:

```
tmux spit-window -h
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux send-keys "run some command" C-m
```

... and repeat the same thing for the next pane ..

But instead I'd like to do something like

```
tmux split-window -h
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux name-pane "tail of X log"
tmux send-keys "run some command" C-m
```

Then later in another script after I'm done with that configuration:

```
tmux selected-named-pane "tail of X log"
tmux send-keys "exit"
```

Of course, I would just loop over the list of panes I want to exit.

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5):

The `NAMES AND TITLES` section in `man tmux` talks about pane titles.

Here's the relevant excerpt:

> A pane's title is typically set by the program running inside the pane and is not modified by tmux.

Instead of using pane names, may I recommend using pane id number. "pane id" is the unique number for the current tmux session. It's just a number prefixed by "%", example "%5".

This is how you get pane id for the current pane: `tmux display-message -p "#{pane_id}"`.

By saving this id somewhere, you can easily reference it somewhere. Here's the example code:

```
tmux split-window -h
tmux select-pane -t 0

# save a pane id to a shell variable
current_pane_id=$(tmux display-message -p "#{pane_id}")

# now save the shell variable to tmux user option (user options are prefixed with @)
tmux set -g @some_variable_name "$current_pane_id"
```

Later, when you want to reference saved pane from another script:

```
# get saved pane id to a shell variable
pane_id="$(tmux show -g @some_variable_name)"

# use -t flag to specify the "target" where the keys are sent
tmux send-keys -t "$pane_id" "exit"
```